# How can I run the Blackberry 10 Simulator (VMWare VMX) in a Windows Azure VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, azure

I'm having some issues running the BB10 Simulator in my azure vm, but before I give up, I thought I'd reach out to the experts. My vm in Windows Azure is Windows Server 2012. It has 2 gigs of memory and more than enough drive space. When I installed the simulator from http://developer.blackberry.com/develop/simulator/, I was not immediately able to run the VMX file as instructed. Some research showed me that I needed VMWare Player, so I installed it too. Now, when I double-click the VMX file, it opens VMWare Player and shows a black screen for a moment before returning to a menu where I can select VM's to start. The BB10 Simulator is the only VM in the list. I can try to "Play" it again, but the same thing happens again.

[image: VM List]

I suspect that I can't use the azure vm as a host for the bb10 vm. On the other hand, I'm hoping there's some way to get around this and be able to use it since I have several hours invested in the azure vm already. Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I found a log file for VMWare Workstation that shows the progress of loading the VM:

```
<Action><Time>1409951292</Time><Act>ViewMode</Act><ID>c3 a5 fe 35 00 52 68 9e-34 58 47 86 86 25 6a f9</ID><Detail>Console</Detail></Action>
<Action><Time>1409951293</Time><Act>ConnectToServer</Act><ID></ID><Detail>VMware Workstation 10.0.3 (local hostd)</Detail></Action>
<Action><Time>1409951294</Time><Act>PowerOnVM</Act><ID>c3 a5 fe 35 00 52 68 9e-34 58 47 86 86 25 6a f9</ID><Detail>other</Detail></Action>
<Action><Time>1409951294</Time><Act>HardwareVersion</Act><ID>c3 a5 fe 35 00 52 68 9e-34 58 47 86 86 25 6a f9</ID><Detail>7</Detail></Action>
```

Not sure what that means, though. :)

Comment: I upgraded to VMWare Workstation just now and it behaves exactly the same as Player.

Comment: I am running on Windows 7, not Azure, but I went to the Start menu and found "Blackberry 10 Simulator", then clicked that to run it.  I had earlier tried to navigate to and click the BlackBerry10Simulator virtual machine object in Windows Explorer, but that clearly did not work.  Eventually re-read the instructions and figured out what it meant: http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_installing.html